# Read only specific lines

Tags: python, python-3.x

I only want to read certain lines, for example lines in the range from 0 to 10 and the program should check the correctness of the data entered by the user.

```
from ftplib import FTP
from ftplib import error_perm

start = 0 # some starting index
end = 5

with open('string.txt', 'rb') as password_list:
     for i,line in enumerate(password_list):
       if(i>start & i<end):
        line=line.replace(b'\n',b'').replace(b'\r',b'')
        password=line.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
start = 0
end = 5
with open('string.txt', 'rb') as fh:
   lines = [i.replace(b'\n',b'').replace(b'\r',b'') for i in fh.readlines()][start:end]
   passwords = [i.decode('utf-8') for i in lines]
```